# using template with specific derived types

Tags: c++, templates, smart-pointers, reference-counting

I'm trying to make a system that has some reference counted object that are derived from the same abstract class ("RCObject"). 
In addition, i am trying to create a template Smart-pointer that should work with objects that derive from "RCObjects".

is there a way for this code to work?
oh, and "RCObjects" is abstract.

the errors i'm getting are that the functions i marked //** : are not defined in the current namespace. (and i don't want to define them there)

checking if an object implements a particular interface is less important to me. what i'm looking for is for my template to be able to use functions from an abstract class that i know all objects in my template will derive from

```
template<class T> 
class Sptr
{
  public:
    Sptr(T* realPtr = 0) : pointee(realPtr)
    {
      init();
    }

    Sptr(const Sptr& rhs) : pointee(rhs.pointee)
    {
      init();
    }

    ~Sptr()
    {
      if (pointee)pointee->removeReference();   //** this function is from "RCObjects"
    }

    Sptr& operator=(const Sptr& rhs)
    {
      if (pointee != rhs.pointee)
      {
        if (pointee) pointee->removeReference();    //** this function is from "RCObjects"
        pointee = rhs.pointee;
        init();
      }

      return *this;
    }

    T* operator->() const
    {
      return pointee;
    }

    T& operator*() const
    {
      return *pointee;
    }

  private:
    T *pointee;

    void init()
    {
      if (pointee == 0) return;
      if (pointee->isShareable() == false)     //** this function is from "RCObjects"
      {
        pointee = new T(*pointee);
      }
      pointee->addReference();                //** this function is from "RCObjects"
    }
};
```

Comment: Give a bit more information about errors or unexpected behavior you get. Don't expect anyone to take your code, compile it and check what's going wrong!

Comment: Also you might want to introduce [static checks](https://github.com/makulik/StaticInterfaces) for your template class parameters, to ensure they implement a particular interface.

Comment: the errors i'm getting are that the functions i marked //** , are not defined in the current namespace.
what are static checks? checking if an object implements a particular interface is less important to me. what i'm looking for is for my template to be able to use functions from an abstract class that i know all objects in my template will derive from

Comment: Did you give a look to [boost::intrusive_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/smart_ptr/intrusive_ptr.html)?

Comment: @orpgol Add this information to your question in a better readable form please!

Comment: Not reproducible. [Live demo](http://ideone.com/aOahs0).